# How can I add class to only comma "," in html if I type digit 1,00,000,000?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How can I add class to digits "," (comma's) 1,00,000,000. I don't want to add class all digits. I only want to add the class ",". 
Can anybody help me, please? 
I am using this code to output the digits

```
<?php 
 $re = "/([^\\s>])(?!(?:[^<>]*)?>)/u"; 
 $str = $figure_one; 
 $subst = "<span class='boxolor'>$1</span>"; 
 $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, number_format($str));
?> 
<span class="price-text">£ </span> 
<a href="<?php echo $investment_link ; ?>"> 
    <span class="" data-value="<?php echo $result ; ?>"><?php echo $result ; ?></span>
</a>
```

I am using smof theme options to output the digits. I type 10000000 and it gives me result like this 1,00,000,000
I want to change the color of ","
How can I do it? Color should be changed only "," not digits.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question would be much more readable if you formatted your code in a friendlier way.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make it difficult simply replace your string

```
 <?php
   $str = "1,00,000,000";
   echo str_replace(",","<span class='red'>,</span>",$str);
 ?>
```

demo : https://eval.in/755705

Answer (score 1):

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "<span class='red'>,</span>");
}
```

pass the value to above function.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using smof theme options. I add digits 10000 in text field and front end should be like this http://prntscr.com/el4i0d How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code.

```js
    function AddComma(txt) {
        if (txt.value.length % 4 == 3) {
            txt.value += ",";
        }
    }
```

```html
<input onkeypress="AddComma(this)"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using smof theme options. I add digits 10000 in text field and front end should be like this http://prntscr.com/el4i0d How can I make this?